What does the cookie "__google_un" do and where does it comes from?
We've recently (this week) noticed a new cookie on our site called __google_un. It hasn't shown up before and I can't find any information online about what it is or what it does.
It's a session cookie with the value of 1.



__google_un
1




Expires/Max-Age:
Session


HostOnly:
true


HttpOnly:
false


Path:
/


SameSite:
None


Secure:
false


Size:
12



We are running Tag Manager with Google Analytics 4 so I assume it's from there, but I find it strange that I've never seen it before and can't find any information about it.
Screenshot of browser storage
When I google all I get is cookie policy pages on other websites where it just says "Description is currently not available." Cookiedatabase.org has nothing either.
